How to completely remove mono on Ubuntu 24.04
I used to need mono for the duplicati software package. Now that's moved to .NET. Since I don't need it and its give apt update problems, how do I completely remove it.

How you remove software depends upon how you originally installed it. There are many possible ways to install software, and no single master command to uninstall. Please edit your question to elaborate on your memory of installing. A link to any instructions you followed would be helpful.

I did : apt install mono-devel gtk-sharp2 libappindicator0.1-cil libmono-2.0-1

"I did: apt install mono-devel gtk-sharp2 libappindicator0.1-cil libmono-2.0-1"
Then simply try working in reverse:

Uninstall exactly the same packages you explicitly installed.
apt remove mono-devel gtk-sharp2 libappindicator0.1-cil libmono-2.0-1


Uninstall any dependencies that are not required by any other packages. ("orphans")
apt autoremove




ALWAYS review the apt output before agreeing to the change.
Many use cases require the use of sudo with apt. It's not included here because your original command did not include it.
[Optional] To remove any global settings in /etc that may have come with packages, use apt purge instead of apt remove


I assumed that's what I should do, but dpkg shows more than 50 packages with mono in it, and wondered if that would get them all
